# Hadoop PIG Helper GROUP error

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am using Hortonworks Sandbox 1.2 and I am pretty new to Hadoop platform.

So here is the error, while I was following the tutorial included by sandbox. In the PIG section, I inserted GROUP code by using PIG Helper. It inserts a code like

```
GROUP %VAR% BY %VAR%
```

And my code seems like this after I complete tutorial.

```
a = LOAD 'nyse_stocks' USING org.apache.hcatalog.pig.HCatLoader();
b = FILTER a BY stock_symbol == 'IBM';
c = GROUP b BY all;
d = FOREACH c GENERATE AVG(b.stock_volume);
DUMP d;
```

It gives error below :

```
[main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: mismatched input ';' expecting LEFT_PAREN
```

I do everything like it is told in tutorial. So where's the error?

EDIT :
I added the PIG logs below.

```
2013-06-24 04:56:16,869 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.Main - Apache Pig version 0.10.1.21 (rexported) compiled Dec 24 2012, 03:01:24
2013-06-24 04:56:16,870 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.Main - Logging error messages to: /hadoop/mapred/taskTracker/sandbox/jobcache/job_201306240450_0001/attempt_201306240450_0001_m_000000_0/work/pig_1372064176867.log
2013-06-24 04:56:20,224 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to hadoop file system at: hdfs://sandbox:8020
2013-06-24 04:56:22,862 [main] INFO org.apache.pig.backend.hadoop.executionengine.HExecutionEngine - Connecting to map-reduce job tracker at: sandbox:50300
2013-06-24 04:56:25,672 [main] WARN org.apache.hadoop.hive.conf.HiveConf - DEPRECATED: Configuration property hive.metastore.local no longer has any effect. Make sure to provide a valid value for hive.metastore.uris if you are connecting to a remote metastore.
2013-06-24 04:56:25,959 [main] INFO hive.metastore - Trying to connect to metastore with URI thrift://sandbox:9083
2013-06-24 04:56:27,956 [main] INFO hive.metastore - Waiting 1 seconds before next connection attempt.
2013-06-24 04:56:28,957 [main] INFO hive.metastore - Connected to metastore.
2013-06-24 04:56:30,552 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: mismatched input ';' expecting LEFT_PAREN
Details at logfile: /hadoop/mapred/taskTracker/sandbox/jobcache/job_201306240450_0001/attempt_201306240450_0001_m_000000
```

Comment: Could you paste the pig log?

Comment: I added the pig logs. And I solve the problem by changing the GROUP epression. Just dropped BY keyword and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

```
c = GROUP b BY all;
```

is incorrect, correct syntax is

```
c = GROUP b all;
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link and look at step 4, the example mentioned over there explain the right method to execute "Group" in pig

Link: (http://hortonworks.com/hadoop-tutorial/hello-world-an-introduction-to-hadoop-hcatalog-hive-and-pig/#pig)